# Illustrator: how can I truly clip an svg image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, clipping-mask

I sometimes use illustrator to make an image, then clip that image. When I export the image to svg all of the clipped parts of the image still affect the boundaries of the svg.

I want a scalable vector image, but I want it to only have the boundaries of my clip.

Comment: Open in a text editor and adjust perhaps. AI's SVG support is still not great in some areas.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. A text editor isn't ideal for me because I have 100+ objects in my scene backgrounds. These aren't complex objects, or special. There's just a lot of them.